# Tracking down a stored procedure's parameters after execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been asked to identify a permissions issue with a stored procedure. This stored procedure behaves in two possible ways depending on what values are used for its parameters.

```
exec ps_my_stored_procedure @a=1, @b=2, @c=3
```

is handled very differently from

```
exec ps_my_stored_procedure @a=5, @b=7, @c=0
```

You could say that `ps_my_stored_procedure` is divided logically into two completely separate processes.

Using `dm_exec_procedure_stats` and `dm_exec_query_stats`, I can find the execution plan which shows the SQL of the stored procedure used.  I have not been able however, to recover how the parameters were defined and with what values.

Is it possible using `dm_exec_procedure_stats` and `dm_exec_query_stats` and any other management views to reconstruct the execution of the stored procedure that shows the values used for its parameters.

What I'd really like is to find in cache, is the actual execution of the stored procedure so that I can execute it as is using `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'someone'` to resolve the permissions issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the execution plan you can view it as xml, and search for compiled parameter values

For example, this is an actual snippet of an execution plan from one of the queries in my plan cache:

```
   <ParameterList>
      <ColumnReference Column="@P69" ParameterCompiledValue="'2015-06-10 00:00:00.0000000'" />
       <ColumnReference Column="@P68" ParameterCompiledValue="'somestring'" />
   </ParameterList>
```

If your plans get reused it will show the value at the time of compilation though.

Answer (score 11):

I often use the following query taken from http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#otherreasons to return the sniffed values. Another way would be to open up the plan in [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) and select the parameters tab. Both the XML method and plan explorer method will show the runtime values assuming that you are viewing the actual execution plan.

```
DECLARE @dbname    nvarchar(256),
        @procname  nvarchar(256)

SELECT @dbname  = '',
       @procname = '' -- enter proc name

; WITH basedata AS (
   SELECT qs.plan_handle,
            qs.statement_start_offset/2 AS stmt_start,
          qs.statement_end_offset/2 AS stmt_end,
          est.encrypted AS isencrypted, est.text AS sqltext,
          epa.value AS set_options, qp.query_plan,
          charindex('<ParameterList>', qp.query_plan) + len('<ParameterList>')
             AS paramstart,
          charindex('</ParameterList>', qp.query_plan) AS paramend
   FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
   CROSS  APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) est
   CROSS  APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(qs.plan_handle,
                                            qs.statement_start_offset,
                                            qs.statement_end_offset) qp
   CROSS  APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle) epa
   WHERE  est.objectid  = object_id (@procname)
     AND  est.dbid      = db_id(@dbname)
     AND  epa.attribute = 'set_options'
), next_level AS (
   SELECT plan_handle,stmt_start, set_options, query_plan,
          CASE WHEN isencrypted = 1 THEN '-- ENCRYPTED'
               WHEN stmt_start >= 0
               THEN substring(sqltext, stmt_start + 1,
                              CASE stmt_end
                                   WHEN 0 THEN datalength(sqltext)
                                   ELSE stmt_end - stmt_start + 1
                              END)
          END AS Statement,
          CASE WHEN paramend > paramstart
               THEN CAST (substring(query_plan, paramstart,
                                   paramend - paramstart) AS xml)
          END AS params
   FROM   basedata
)

SELECT set_options AS [SET]
        , n.stmt_start AS Pos
        , n.Statement
       , CR.c.value('@Column', 'nvarchar(128)') AS Parameter
       , CR.c.value('@ParameterCompiledValue', 'nvarchar(128)') AS [Sniffed Value]
       , CAST (query_plan AS xml) AS [Query plan]
       , n.plan_handle
FROM   next_level n
CROSS  APPLY   
        n.params.nodes('ColumnReference') AS CR(c)
ORDER  BY n.set_options, n.stmt_start, Parameter
```

Comment: This is not working for SQL 2016 SP parameters, as `n.params.nodes` XML does not contain `ColumnReference` element. It contains this only: `<ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
  <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
</ScalarOperator>
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="NULL">
  <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
</ScalarOperator>` Does not work in 2012 either. What's missing?